# javascript document.write("<base href="">"); not working

Tags: javascript

The following code work :

```
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
```

But this not work:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
document.write("<base href='http://" + document.location.host + "' />");    
</script>    

<script type="text/javascript">    
document.write("<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">");    
</script>
```

On http://www.customtemplates.com.au/

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape your quotes:

```
document.write("<base href=\"http://www.w3schools.com/\" target=\"_blank\">");
```

Or simpler with simple quotes:

```
document.write('<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting double-quotes. Try switching to single quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
document.write('<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">');    
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use document.write. Use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/document.createElement) instead.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; //get the head-Element

var script = document.createElement('script'); //Create a script-element
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); //Set an attribute

var base = document.createElement('base'); //Create a base-element
base.setAttribute('href', document.location); //Set an attribute

script.appendChild(base); //Append the base-element to the script-element
head.appendChild(script);  //Append the script-element to the head-element
```

Comment: Cannot be used to set base href.